# Magento2: Trigger fetch estimate rates

Tags: magento2

I am creating a module where it removes a specific Shipping Method whenever this field value matches certain criteria. The conditions are handled from the backend where it uses the Magento 2 plugin feature. Now I want to trigger the estimates rates through knockout js.

[image]

Now my questions are, **how are we able to trigger the request estimate shipping methods?**

[image]

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Magento core is using rate processors that depend on the address type to load the rates (either from cache or through API), see for example [Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address.js).

You can see how the core handles shipping address updates in the
    [Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-service](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rate-service.js)
     model.

So in general you will just want to make sure, that the shippingAddress emits that it was updated (via quote.shippingAddress.valueHasMutated()) and the cacheKey of the shippingAddress object is changed, when your custom field is updated.